# distance between two random poisson points

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Consider n random poison points which are distributed according to parameter $\lambda$. Two random points are chosen. Is it true to say CDF of the distance between two points equals to:
$$F_{d}(x)=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{k=n}\left(1- \sum\limits_{l=0}^{k-1}
\frac{\left(\lambda x \right) ^{k}}{k!}\right) e^{-\lambda x}} {n}$$

Comment: Statement is confusing.  "$\lambda$ per unit area" "uniformly in the disk".  What is the distribution?

Comment: @herbsteinberg: presumably the number of points in any part of the disk with area $a$ has a Poisson distribution with expectation $\lambda a$ and the numbers of points in two disjoint parts are independent

Comment: I think there is a positive probability $(1+\lambda \pi R^2)\exp(-\lambda \pi R^2)$ that there are not two points in your disk

Comment: But if you consider all points in the disk, then this is [a different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135766/average-distance-between-two-points-in-a-circular-disk)