# What is the mean distance between two random points in an annulus?

Tags: geometry

What is the mean distance between two random points in an annulus?

I have found the formula for two random points in a circle [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135766/average-distance-between-two-points-in-a-circular-disk) but not an annulus.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck? You might start by defining some parameters and variables and writing down some formulas ...